# How to Link MVC Model data with Angular JS Model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

I am using MVC Razor View with AngularJS.

I am creating the UserMaster object in controller and passing to the view

```
Function AddNewUser() As ActionResult
       Dim objUser As New UserMaster()
        Return View("UserMaster", objUserMaster)
End Function
```

In View, By using HTML helper classes the text box and validation controls will be created

```
@<div ng-app ng-controller="UserController">
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserName)
```

In the client side using the following statement the AngularJS model is created

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           function UserController($scope, $http) {
           $scope.UserData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
           }
    </script>
```

The server side validations(which I have written in the UserMaster Class) are working fine in client side, The razor engine is automatically doing that by generating client side validation scripts.

I am automatically getting flourished model in server side after submit.

But I am not able to manipulate/get the model data in client side using AngularJS (by using $scope.UserData.UserName). I want to access the UserName value inside the text box when the user is modifying it by using angular JS.. How?

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: yes... I will update the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be possible by using htmlAttributes in MVC - 5

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserName, New With {Key .htmlAttributes = New With {Key .ng_model = "model.UserName"}})
```

we have to use **ng_model** insted of **ng-model** and MVC will render as **ng-model** in runtime